# Is there a collection of national flags in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have tried to search, but I have not been able to found any repository with the flags of the most common countries defined with TikZ. It must be very possible as most flags are really vectors.

Comment: Not that I know of, but you could take an SVG rendering (say, from here: http://www.bastisoft.de/misc/flags/) and convert it to TikZ.

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: Great idea and link, thanks! On a sidenote, sadly Brazil is not in that flag list. =P

Comment: @Paulo: In that case, if anyone wants to do a "proof of concept" here then they should do the Brazilian flag!  (I got as far as "Denmark" before I stopped looking.)

Comment: @Andrew: Wikimedia has Denmark *and* Brazil: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:SVG_sovereign_state_flags

Comment: @Jake: I bow to your superior searching skills.  I got the following page from Wikipedia when I searched: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:SVG_flags

Comment: @Jake: I'm with @Andrew, you have some sort of Jedi searching skills. =)

Comment: @PauloCereda, I'm trying to draw our flag here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438149/14757

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Update**

Sadly, this solution no longer works (as of TeX Live 2015).  In the change history of `minitoc`:

> 2015/07/13
>
> - Jean-Pierre F. Drucbert passed away in 2009. So this package is now
>     looking for a maintainer.
> - Reduce size of documentation, by
>     eliminating flags and other images, from 25+mb to less than 2mb.

You can retrieve the original version of the documentation from the TeXLive historic archive [here](ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2014/tlnet-final/archive/minitoc.doc.tar.xz).

**Original answer**

The astonishingly bizarre documentation for the [`minitoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minitoc) package has done most of the work for you. (Although with `.png` images.) So for any flag you can think of the following will work: (You can also find maps as well.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% change the year to match your current distribution up to 2014
\graphicspath{{/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/doc/latex/minitoc/}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{brazil-f}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{vanuatu-f}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{belarus-f}
\end{document}
```

Just for entertainment, here are the flags of Brazil, Vanuatu, and Belarus.

[image: Brazil Vanuatu Belarus flags]

Comment: That is _weird_

Comment: Note: This won’t work with MiKTeX – for two reasons: especially for this package the flag files are not included in minitoc’s documentation directory, and generally the whole documentation subtree is unfortunately not included into the filename database. One could, of course, install all missing files in a local texmf tree and then give the absolute path or use `\graphicspath`  – or put the needed files into the document directory.

Comment: 5 interesting flags: Poland, Indonesia, Monaco, Austria, and Peru.

Comment: @Speravir: I see. Thanks. This comment will be deleted shortly.

Comment: Does this still work in 2019? I can't find the flags on my disk (TeX Live @arch)

Comment: @pasbi No it doesn't. The package was changed in 2015 and all the flags were removed. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @pasbi There is a new package, now. See my answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/594051/101651

Answer (score 32):

Now (April 2021) there is!

Wilhelm Haager created the [package `worldflags`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/worldflags).

Here some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{worldflags}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
Standard flags

\worldflag{IT}
\worldflag{BR}
\worldflag{AD}\vspace{10pt}

Flags with special dimensions

\worldflag{CH}
\worldflag{GB}
\worldflag{VA}\vspace{10pt}

There are also some options 

(for the complete list see the package documentation)

\worldflag[length=3cm]{EU}
\worldflag[grid]{UNO}
\worldflag[noemblem]{EC}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, I had to update everything on MikTeX to be able to use it as the package is very new! Although I have to add, that for some flags using an aspect ratio where the horizontal length is smaller than the vertical width results into an odd output. An example of what I mean can be seen when using `\worldflag[length=1cm, width=2cm]{US}`.

Comment: @owmal Unfortunately, I'm not the package author, you should write to him to report the bug.

Comment: Thank you, I have just contacted him. :)

Answer (score 11):

[`bclogo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bclogo) also includes some of them in format `.mps`.

[image]

Comment: The set is quite limited though. The flags included in the answer of @Ignasi (6 November 2012) are the only ones currently included (checked on 19 January 2016).

Answer (score 6):

There is a [PSTricks](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-base) based package [**pst-flags**](https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-flags)

Download the zip files from [GitHub project page](https://github.com/manthanwar/PST-Flags) and put it in your tex file path, see [package documentation](https://github.com/manthanwar/PST-Flags/blob/main/pst-flags/doc/pst-flags-doc.pdf)

Usage: \flagTwoLetterCountryCode[width].

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-flags}
\begin{document}
Flag of US: \rput(0,0){\flagUS[2]}
\end{document}
```