# National flag using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a collection of national flags in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18516/is-there-a-collection-of-national-flags-in-tikz)

I need to draw a Kenyan national flag using TikZ or using TeX in general.

Comment: Related: [Drawing a flag with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57668/5764)

Comment: The easiest way would be to `\includegraphics` [an already existing graphic that is legal to use](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Flag_of_Kenya.svg&page=1). What features are you looking for that you would get by drawing it yourself/again?

Comment: While, as it is, this question seems a bit too _do it for me_ to me, I could see it resulting in a package (or just code) that can draw standard three-stripe (horizontal/vertical) flags with any combination of colors; and potentially a variant with a waving flag, like in the question @Werner pointed to. (And someone might add an animated pstricks version `:)`)

Comment: So, @Nyang': 
[Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please show some attempt you've made in achieving this and specify what you're struggling with. The point of this Q&A site is to solve specific problems, not to have other people do your work.

Comment: Duplicate of [Does there exist somewhere a collection of country flags in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18516/2693).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With no downloading:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/doc/latex/minitoc/}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{kenya-f}
\end{document}
```

See [Is there a collection of national flags in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18516/2693) for the original question.

[image: kenya flag]

Answer (score 4):

[The OP asked originally:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/81578/4)

> Is there an easy way?

*Yes, there is.*

---

I imagine you want a Scalable Vector Graphic (SVG).[Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) has a lot of national flags.
Via [Wikipedia:Flag of Kenya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Kenya) I could find a graphic of the [flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Flag_of_Kenya.svg&page=1) of [Kenya](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Flag_of_Kenya.svg) in the the Scalable Vector Graphic (SVG) format.
Download that file and save it locally (`.svg`).

As pdf(La)TeX/[`graphicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) cannot include files in the SVG format you need to convert it to PDF. The easiest way to do this is probably an [online converter](http://www.fileformat.info/convert/image/svg2pdf.htm) (but any converter will do).
As the flag's aspect ratio is 3:2 put a resolution like 300 × 200 in the text boxes that requires the output's size. Download the resulting file and save is as a `.pdf` file.

In your TeX document and with the help of the [`graphicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package you can now use `\includegraphics[<options>]{filename}`.

You most likely need to re-size the resulting image, this can be done with the key-value options `width`, `height`, `totalheight`, `keepaspectratio` and/or `scale` (see the [`graphicx`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/graphicx) manual for more information).

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{81578_flag}
\end{document}
```